# Error building sample driver: An SDK corresponding to WDK version '8.1' was not found

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, windows-10, wdk

I used one Windows Driver samples from github ([Filesys](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys)) and tried to build it on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015.

I have installed both:

- WDK8.1 with its SDK
- WDK10

But when i try to build a project i see this error message:

```
An SDK corresponding to WDK version '8.1' was not found. Please install the SDK before building.    minispy (Filter\minispy)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets
```

but SDK of 8.1 is already installed.

Is there any option in Visual studio that i could use to point it to SDK 8.1?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and the solution
is sdk version 10 released after VS 2015 .

You should download and install it manually. I used the following link for downloading sdk :
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Also see this link for help with downloading and installing sdk 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpwdkblog/archive/2015/08/21/windows-10.aspx
good luck

Comment: @Reflection...After installing SDK ,error will be resolved?

Comment: @Ronil yes, i had this error and after install sdk problem solved

Answer (score 7):

In this case, you may missed No.3.

Check following points:

1. Install Visual Studio 2015
2. Install Visual C++ (Not installed by default)
3. Install Windows SDK for Windows 10 (Not installed by default)
4. Install WDK 10 (Download separately)
5. Upgrade project from WDK 8.1 (for more detail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt270257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Currently, 
Visual Studio 2015 supports WDK 10.
Visual Studio 2013 supports WDK 8.1.
In my environment, Visual Studio 2015 may not support WDK 8.1.
When build in WindowsUserModeDriver8.1 with VS2015, an error was occurred: prop is not found.

WDK 10 supports build drivers for Windows 10 / 8.1 / 8 (/ 7?).
(see also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/hardware/dn914754%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

To build Windows 8.1 driver,  follow below.

1. Open project properties
2. Navigate to Configuration Properties > General
3. Check: Platform Toolset Windows****ModeDriver10.0
4. Navigate to Configuration Properties > Driver settings
5. Check: Target OS Version: Windows 8.1
6. Check: Target Platform: Desktop (Default: Universal)

Answer (score 2):

You are likely targeting the wrong platform toolset. To build a driver for Windows 10, you need to target one of the Windows 10 platform toolset (WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 or WindowsUserModeDriver10.0). If you want to use SDK 8.1, then you should use the WDK 8.1 platform toolsets (WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1 or WindowsUserModeDriver8.1).

You cannot use the 10.0 toolsets and try to make them point to SDK 8.1 because there were some key changes to how files are laid on disk between the two kits. Using the appropriate toolset should hopefully fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed all the instructions during the installation of VS? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx

After correct installation I have handled the problem.

(Optional)
Did you install Windows 10 SDK?
Download link: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk